# I want to get a variable from a file using python

Tags: python

I have text file which contain's the following:

```
 List : 1 2 3, 5 6 7
 N:7
```

And I want to fetch the value of N which is 7 :

My code :

```
 def imp_res():
    # Get the content of the named resource as a string.
    data = resources.GetResource(
       'experimental/users/abhijitsahani/file/input.txt', 
         mode='rt')

    for line in data:
       if 'N' in line:
          val = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
    print('Content :', val)
```

Current Output:

```
  content : N
```

Expected Output:

```
  Content : 7
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure this is really what you are running?

Comment: @Avi319170, I agree with tomjn, it works for me.

Comment: yes. i am getting N

Comment: is there any other this can be achieved?

Comment: @Avi319170 is your data a file object or a string?

Comment: That probably means that your data is not what you/we think. I'd have a close look at the file.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? E.g., print out the value of `line.split(':')` etc.

Comment: @Avi319170 If `data` is a string I get N, if it is a file it works. So either change your `resources.GetResource` line to `open` or wrap data in `io.StringIO`

Comment: @Roope the o/p is ['N']

Comment: ```>>> def imp_res():
...     with open('/home/akash.pagar/DjangoProjects/stackoverflow/input.txt', 'r') as f:
...             for line in f:
...                     line = line.strip()
...                     if line.split(':')[0] == 'N':
...                             print(line.split(':')[-1])
``` its working. with open function also. try this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data` is a string (like the code comment suggests) and not a file (like the title suggests) then you are just iterating through each character of the string and you just end up assigning `N` to val.

There are a couple of solutions.

1. Change whatever `resources.GetResource` to a simple `open`
2. Wrap `data` in `io.StringIO`

e.g.

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO("""List : 1 2 3, 5 6 7
N:7
""")
# data = data.read()  # What I think your code is doing
for line in data:
    if 'N' in line:
        val = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
print('Content :', val)
```

will print

```
Content : 7
```

I expect what your code is doing is putting a `read()` call on `data` before iterating over it. Uncomment that line and you'll get

```
Content : N
```